# How do I deform one object using another object as a guide?

Tags: modeling

I am not too sure if I am making myself clear, but is it possible to have, say, 
object A with 20 vertices and object B with 15 vertices.

Is there an automated way to deform object A to resemble object B? I'm horrible at judging shape/sculpting and was wondering if there was an easier way to shape things.

Comment: Welcome to the site, BlenderScrub. Unfortunately, your question as posed does not fit well with the scope of the site. You might want to take the [tour](http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour), and visit the [help center](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help) for information on how to bring your question within the scope of the site. That said, whether there is an automated way will depend quite a bit on what exactly object A and object B are.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I'm not very sure how do I bring it into scope? Or rather, I'm not sure what part is incorrect. Could you please elaborate? Sorry, I'm rather new

Comment: Are you trying to animate A->B or do you want to duplicate B with more vertices?  some things to look at: Shape Keys, Retopology, Subsurf.

Comment: I'm planning to duplicate it.

Answer (score 2):

A [shrinkwrap modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/deform/shrinkwrap.html) can be used to deform one object to the surface of another.

Retopology is a more manual approach that uses [automatic transform snapping](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/snap.html#transform-snapping) of vertices to another surface to make a clean duplicate of an object.